# Cannot install PyCall.jl with Julia 1.6.3 build on FreeBSD 13

Tags: julia, freebsd, python-3.10, pycall.jl

I am trying to install PyCall.jl but I get an error. I have installed (bulit) Python 3.10 in the FreeBSD 13. I also, have separately  created a python 3.10 virtual environment on the OS  from which, I intend to call python packages from.  The error is as below.

```
(dataViz) pkg> add PyCall
   Resolving package versions...
   Installed VersionParsing ─ v1.2.1
   Installed Conda ────────── v1.5.2
   Installed MacroTools ───── v0.5.9
   Installed JSON ─────────── v0.21.2
   Installed PyCall ───────── v1.92.5
    Updating `/usr/home/schroter/dataViz/Project.toml`
  [438e738f] + PyCall v1.92.5
    Updating `/usr/home/schroter/dataViz/Manifest.toml`
  [8f4d0f93] + Conda v1.5.2
  [682c06a0] + JSON v0.21.2
  [1914dd2f] + MacroTools v0.5.9
  [438e738f] + PyCall v1.92.5
  [81def892] + VersionParsing v1.2.1
    Building Conda ─→ `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/299304989a5e6473d985212c28928899c74e9421/build.log`
    Building PyCall → `~/.julia/scratchspaces/44cfe95a-1eb2-52ea-b672-e2afdf69b78f/4ba3651d33ef76e24fef6a598b63ffd1c5e1cd17/build.log`
ERROR: Error building `PyCall`:
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
<string>:1: DeprecationWarning: The distutils.sysconfig module is deprecated, use sysconfig instead
ERROR: LoadError: Couldn't find libpython; check your PYTHON environment variable.

The python executable we tried was python3 (= version 3.10).
Re-building with
    ENV["PYCALL_DEBUG_BUILD"] = "yes"
may provide extra information for why it failed.

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] find_libpython(python::String; _dlopen::typeof(Base.Libc.Libdl.dlopen))
   @ Main ~/.julia/packages/PyCall/3fwVL/deps/buildutils.jl:72
 [3] find_libpython(python::String)
   @ Main ~/.julia/packages/PyCall/3fwVL/deps/buildutils.jl:41
 [4] top-level scope
   @ ~/.julia/packages/PyCall/3fwVL/deps/build.jl:82
 [5] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
 [6] top-level scope
   @ none:5
in expression starting at /home/schroter/.julia/packages/PyCall/3fwVL/deps/build.jl:43
```

The installed modules in Julia are as follows:

```
(dataViz) pkg> status
      Status `/usr/home/schroter/.jlmain/dataViz/Project.toml`
  [336ed68f] CSV v0.9.10
  [54eefc05] Cascadia v1.0.1
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.2.2
  [708ec375] Gumbo v0.8.0
  [cd3eb016] HTTP v0.9.16
  [c3e4b0f8] Pluto v0.17.1
  [05625dda] WebDriver v0.1.2
```

EDIT:
My system wide python is at :`/usr/local/bin/python3`
My python virtual environment is at:`~/.pymain/dataViz/bin/activate.csh`

Would anyone be able to help me in this matter please?

Thanks & Best Regards

Schroter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mentioned setting the `PYTHON` environment variable so this is the likely cause of problems:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/local/bin/python3"
using Pkg
Pkg.build("PyCall")
```

For best results try use Miniconda/Anaconda Python, preferably let Julia install it (I do not know though how easy or difficult it is to install Miniconda on FreeBSD, on any Linux it usually "just works"):

```
ENV["PYTHON"]=""
using Pkg
Pkg.build("PyCall")
```

If you want to rather use some Miniconda:

```
ENV["PYTHON"]="/home/user/miniconda/bin/python"
using Pkg
Pkg.build("PyCall")
```

Let me know if this helped (I do not have a FreeBSD installation to test)

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed reply. I edited the post so to show my python paths. Please have a look. I tried the three methods. First one gave the error I have included in the original post. The other two gave an error saying "[ Info: Downloading miniconda installer ...
ERROR: LoadError: Unsuported OS.
"  Will let you know on any update. Thanks & Best Regards Schroter

Comment: Perhaps your FreeBSD Python has different library files than a standard Python Linux installation. I would try to install Miniconda (there are some tutorials for FreeBSD) and point `ENV["PYTHON"]` to it. Still just an idea what I would try to do :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I managed to install miniconda3 on FreeBSD after adding Linux compatibility layer on it. I set `ENV["PYTHON"]="/usr/home/schroter/miniconda3/bin/python3` and used third method. But still could not install PyCall in Julia. Thanks  & Best Regards Schroter